# If $T$ is an operator on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, can the eigenvalues be complex?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So if we have an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, and $F$ = $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Then, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ could be real- or complex-valued. Correct?

Now, if $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ but $F$ = $\mathbb{R}$, then can $T$ necessarily have complex-valued eigenvalues? If so, when (what criteria must be met)?

Thanks. I'm genuinely curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is an operator on a real vector space. The minimal polynomial of $T$ may have complex roots, but only the real roots are actually eigenvalues.

Example: Let $T$ be the transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

The minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^2+1$. The roots of which are $i, -i$. But there are no non-zero vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $Av = iv$ or $Av = -iv$.

Comment: Does this follow from the concept of "Complexification"? My book (Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler) states the following as a proposition: "Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Then the zeros of the minimal polynomial of T are precisely the eigenvalues of T. We are not covering complexification as part of our class.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure that "follow from" would be appropriate here. But if you "complexify" a real operator, then all of the roots of the minimal polynomial will become eigenvalues.

Comment: As far as the statement "The zeros of the minimal polynomial of $T$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $T$" goes, this is true. However you must remember what field you are working over. If you have a real operator, those complex zeros don't "exist". Your operator doesn't "know" what complex numbers are.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for the clarification. I thought that perhaps there was some connection to abstract algebra where you might have a polynomial solvable in one field but not another field. I just wasn't sure (I need to review that stuff haha). Thanks again!